# Is there a website with "embedded plugins"?

Tags: plugins, free, wordpress.com

As I am using WordPress.com (special version) with no plugin support, I have a hard time implementing a couple of elements I would like.
I found out the ability to add Facebook chat through JavaScript on my website, and wonder if anyone know about a site that summaries a compilation of free in code JavaScript plugins like this.

I tried googling around but only find websites marketing their own paid widgets.